# Acessing the value of a pointer after the pointer has been deleted

Tags: c++, pointers

So im a student and I have a simple homework about the fundamentals of C++. Everything worked fine so far, but now I have a problem that I can´t seem to figure out.

The classes I wrote need to be tested in a main method provided by the professor. The problem is, that he creates a pointer to an object, then deletes the pointer but afterwards wants to print the object. For some reason that doesn´t work with the code I wrote.

Maybe I didn´t understand pointers enough, I learned them with this website:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm

I think part of my problem is also in the "Add" Method (you´ll see what I mean). The head of that method is given by the professor. If I understood it correctly, &args means it returns the adress.

Sorry in advance that my code is in german, but it shouldn´t influence that you guys can understand it.
Also sorry in advance if I missed important details or didn´t write detailed enough what my problem is or enough of my code.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I don´t really know what to do to solve the problem.

--------------This is the code provided by the professor-----------------

**I am not allowed to edit this**

```cpp
   int main(){
    Class1 Object1List[2];

    Class2  Object2.1= Class2(std::string("),...);  //all further parameters are strings
    Class2* Object2.2= new Class2(std:string(""),...);

    Class3  Object3.1 = Class3(std::string(""),...);
    Class3* Object3.2 = new Class3 (std::string(""),...);

    Object1List[0]=new Class1(Object3.1);
    Object1List[0]->Add(Object2.1);
    Object1List[0]->Add(*Object2.2);

    Object1List[1]=new Class1(Object3.2);
    Object1List[1]->Add(Object2.1);
    Object1List[1]->Add(*Object2.2);

    delete Object2.2;
    delete Object3.2;

    //for loop to print and afterwards delete both elements in Object1List
}
```

```cpp
--------Class1--------------------------------
class Class1 {

    static const int maxEntries = 10;
    int m_numEntries=0;

    Class2 m_Class2;
    Class3* m_pList[maxEntries];
public:    
    Class1(Class2& objClass2);
    ~Class1();

    void Add(Class3& arg);
    void Print()const;
}
//cpp
  //constructor
this->m_Zeitschrift = zeitschrift;
//deconstructor sets all elements in the list to a nullptr

void Class1::Add(Class2& args){
    if(currentNumberOfEntries <=maxNumberOfEntries){
    currentNumberOfEntries++;
    class3List[currentNumberOfEntries] = &arg;
    }
}

//print
void Class1::Print(){
std::cout << "Class2: " << std::endl;
    m_Class2.Print();
    std::cout << "Class3list: " << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_numEntries;i++) {
        m_pList[i]->Print();
    }
}
```

I expect the print method to "just" write the things in the list. Instead, it tells me it can´t print, instead it says this (translated from german):

Thrown exception: "reading access (forbidden/injured/hurt/not allowed)" (lesezugriffsverletzung)
**std::_String_alloc > >::_Get_data**(...) returned 0xCDCDCDE9.

Comment: I don't know the exact task your teacher has given you, but most of the time containers create a copy of the element stored and they are responsible for managing it. You are only storing the pointer to an element, so your container can never know if the element is still alive, whether or not it can `delete` this object etc.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I think this would be a good answer ;)

Comment: @churill Too many assumptions to make it an answer IMO. The fact that standard containers work like this doesn't mean that user-defined ones have to. We need [mcve] to answer this question properly :)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen If you think so ^^   The exact task would also be helpful. I mean a description of _how `Add` should be implemented_.

Comment: Your Add method store a pointer to the argument. So it does not create a copy of the data you passed. If you delete the object in the main, the pointer in the container still points to deleted memory (dangling pointer). So when you try to access it, the OS may (or may not) killed your program with SegV (accessing to a forbidden memory area). It is undefined behavior, so the OS may not be able to see the dangling pointer and your program keeps running. The solution is to not delete the pointers until you are done with it.

Comment: If you want to understand pointers, I recommend watching the videos of mycodeschool on pointers. You'll fall in love with pointers after that.

Comment: @lucieon Though falling in love with pointers is not recommended in modern c++ ;)

Comment: I changed my code to maybe help you guys understand it better @Yksisarvinen. Please note that some parts are given by the professor and are not to be edited! (Nico238).
The "exact task" is basicly, that we got the main method and need to make it run without problems. The add method is not restriced by anything else than the head.

Comment: The code is incomplete. You should put in more effort if you want others to help you. Post code that compiles. What is `m_Zeitschrift`?

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, you should be making a copy of the elements passed in. For this you can use the copy constructor.

```
void Class1::Add(Class2& arg){
  if(currentNumberOfEntries <=maxNumberOfEntries){
    currentNumberOfEntries++;
    class3List[currentNumberOfEntries] = new Class2(arg);
  }
}
```

Be sure to delete the elements in you destructor.

Note that the comaprison bewtween `currentNumberOfEntries` 
 and `maxNumberOfEntries` should be `<` and not `<=`.

Note that `currentNumberOfEntries` is incremented before index based assignment, so the last two lines should prob. be exchanged like this:

```
void Class1::Add(Class2& arg){
  if(currentNumberOfEntries < maxNumberOfEntries){
    class3List[currentNumberOfEntries] = new Class2(arg);
    currentNumberOfEntries++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! Sadly this did not fix the error entirely (although I can see that one source of errors has been erased). The error message I mentioned above is shown again:
"Thrown exception: "reading access (forbidden/injured/hurt/not allowed)" (lesezugriffsverletzung) std::_String_alloc > >::_Get_data(...) returned 0xCDCDCDE9." (translated from german)

This is thrown if I want to print the List again. So for some reason the adress is saved again instead of the Class2 Object itself.

Comment: Also little update: it doesn´t matter, if I delete the pointers before or after it tries to print.

Comment: well that is code not shown, so I have no Idea why that doesn't work.

Comment: Well I didn´t add it bc its just a very simple. but ill add it here (head is given by the professor again):

void Class2::Print const{
 std::cout << "attribute1: " << attribute1 << ", attribute2: " << attribute 2 << std:endl;
}

The attributes are public attributes of the class.

Comment: It"s hard to help you you because you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example. The error is prob. in your object/memory managment for `class3List`

Comment: A printing but incomplete version can be found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36825ffd06e6567a).

Comment: I don´t really know what to add, because the other 2 classes are really simple classes with just a constructor and a print function, as well as 2 public String attributes. The print method I already wrote, and it can be applied to both classes.

The constructor is just this->attribute1=parameter1;

Comment: you should provide an example that compiles like in the link to the example in the comment above. You should provide at the very least, the whole code of `Class1` so that we can see how you manage the objects passed via `Add`.

Comment: I added the complete Class1 code. Thanks already for your help so far!

Comment: But we can also just end this here, because my deadline to hand it in is over, and te professor will explain what mistake I made. Thank you for all your help anyways!